# Alternating controller lights, good battery

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

I've looked up the "alternating controller lights" issue and found that this is typically an indicator of low battery.  However, when I check the Xbox menu, I see that I still have two bars worth of power left - I expect most electronics to not bother me until one or zero bars.

The battery, charger, controller, and console are all barely a month old and all Microsoft brand.  So it's *relatively* unlikely that I'm dealing with faulty hardware.

What else could be causing this error condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 360 remote begins the low battery alert at two bars, then increases the frequency of the flashing (as well as disabling vibration) at one bars.

Your controller is fine, it's just hungry.

Comment: Two bars, really?  What a wimp.

Comment: My personal recommendation would be to just get another battery pack and charge them alternately.

Comment: I do have another pack. It's just rather annoying to me that they have the alert threshold set so high.

Comment: I agree, but I can imagine they'd get considerably more complaints if it waited until the middle of a match to throw a critical error. In this way, it gives you plenty of time to swap out or charge up before your controller dies in the middle of a match.

Comment: @Krael It would be cooler if you could load another batterypack in the controller like you would a gun. If it dies in the middle of the match you could reload like a pro ;)

Comment: @Lyrion too bad that you would not be able to shout "Recharging" in voice chat, as the mic is powered by the controller. :(